# Won't return the correct value in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have this problem. I can't get the correct value of `txtHint`.
I have a database named balance, in it there's `balance_id`,`student_id`,`total_balance`.

here's the line of code:

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="student_idx" name="student_idx" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
<span><input id="txtHint" name="txtHint" type = "hidden"></span>
<button name="save" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large">



if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

            $query = mysql_query("select * from student as st,balance ORDER BY st.student_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());

              $amount = $_POST['amount'];
              $student_idx = $_POST['student_idx'];
              $balance = $_POST['txtHint'];

                  $difference = $balance - $amount;

                  mysql_query("UPDATE balance SET total_balance = '$difference' WHERE student_id = '$student_idx'")or die(mysql_error());

?>

<?php } ?>
```

and here's the code for `getuser.php`

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM balance WHERE student_id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['balance'];
}
?>
```

the problem is that when I have a `total_balance` of 150, and I have paid an amount of 50, the result is -50. I don't know what's wrong in this.

Comment: I would check the value of `$balance` before you calculate `$difference`; I bet it's value is `0`, which would give you a result of `-50`.

Comment: how do i check the value of it ?

Comment: Are you familiar with code debugging? If you're using an IDE that allows you to set breakpoints, you can inspect the values of the code as it is executing. If not, just try echoing out the three amount values or use `var_dump($difference)` (for example) to dump out the value and data type of the variable before you do the mysql_query.

Comment: oh i see now ! it worked ! Thank you !
and i'm sorry for posting like this with such small mistake

Comment: What was the issue? It would help future visitors if you posted an answer to your own question.